# Is the possibility of deleting the application remotely?

Tags: android

Can an application be remotely uninstalled/deleted?

Comment: I hope not. That would be annoying for the user.

Comment: If you're Google, yes. Otherwise: no. ;)

Answer (score 1):

We cannot uninstall an application without user intervention, therefore uninstalling/deleting an application remotely is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually possible but you cannot do it. Only Google can (to remove malware downloaded from the Market I guess)

If you want controls like a remote wipe of data/ encryption though, read about [Device Admin](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html)